# How to avoid distance ordering in large scale billboard rendering with transparency

Tags: c++, opengl, transparency

**Setting the scene:**

I am rendering a height map (vast non-transparent surface) with a large amount of billboards on it (typically grass, flowers and so on).

The billboards thus have a mostly transparent color map applied, with only a few pixels colored to produce the grass or leaf shapes and such. Note that the edges of those shapes use a bit of transparency gradient to make them look smoother, but I have also tried with basic, binary color/transparent textures.

Pseudo rendering code goes like so:

```
map->render();
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
wildGrass->render();
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

Where the wildGrass render instruction renders multiple billboards at various locations in a single OGL call.

The issue I am experiencing has to do with transparency and the fact that billboards apparently hide each-other, even on their transparent area. However the height-map solid background is correctly displayed on those transparent parts.

**Here's the glitch:**

- Left is with an explicit fragment shader discard on fully transparent pixels
- Right is without the discard, clearly showing the billboard's flat quad

[image]

Based on my understanding of OGL blending and some reading, it seems that the solution is to have a controlled order of rendering, starting  from the most distant objects to the closest, so that the color buffer is filled properly in the end.

I am desperately hoping that there is another way... The ordering here would typically vary depending on the point of view, which means it has to be applied in-real-time for each frame. Plus the nature of those particular billboards is to be produced in a -very large- number... Performance alert!

Any suggestions or is my approach of blending wrong?

Comment: Perhaps [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50720534/implementing-depth-testing-for-semi-transparent-objects) helps.

Comment: Try a texture without semi transparent texels and [Multisample anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multisample_anti-aliasing)

Comment: @httpdigest actually disabling depth creates another problem (which is that billboards are displayed even when the map should hide them), but you made an interesting remark: depth writting also occur on fully transparent pixels. I did not know that ! However I don't think it will help me on this particular problem

Comment: @Rabbid76 no semi-transparent pixel coupled with explicit discards in the fragment shader works indeed, BUT, it produces a damn ugly result !! Not to mention that those kind of textures are not easy to come by. However it can be a short term solution.

Comment: @Ripi2 Thank you, I will take the time to study this post soon

Comment: @Rabbid76 Ah I get it now - interesting indeed, I will give it a try shortly and come back here with results

Comment: @httpdigest Right! The second comment made it all make sense, I had not caught the distinction between testing & writing

Comment: Thank you everyone, looks like I have at least two paths to explore here. I will post my findings & results as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Did not work for me:**

@httpdigest's suggestion to disable depth buffer writing:

It worked essentially for billboards with the same texture (and possibly a specific type of texture, like wild grass for instance), because the depth inconsistencies are not visually noticeable - however introducing another texture, say a flower with drastically different colours, will immediately highlights those mistakes.

**Solution:**

@Rabbid76's suggestion to use not-semi-transparent textures with multi-sampling & anti-aliasing: I believe this is the way to go for best visual effect with reasonably low cost on performance.

**Alternative solution:**

I found an intermediary solution which is probably the cheapest in performance to the expense of quality. I still use textures with gradient transparent edges, but instead of discarding fully transparent pixels, I introduced a degree of tolerance, for example any pixel with alpha < 0.6 is discarded - the value is found experimentally to find the right balance.

With this approach:

- I still perform depth tests, so output is correct
- Textures quality is degraded/look less smooth - but reasonably so
- The glitches on semi-transparent pixels still appear - but are nearly not noticeable
- See capture below

**So to conclude:**

- My solution is a cheap and simple approximation giving less smooth visual result
- Best result can be obtained by rendering all the billboards to a multi-sampled texture resolve with anti-aliasing and finally output the result in a full screen quad. There are probably to ways to do this:

  - Either rendering the map first and use the resulting depth buffer when rendering the billboards
  - Or render both the map and billboards on the multi-sampled texture
- Note that the above approaches are both meant to avoid having to distance-base sort a large number of billboards - but this remains a valid option and I have read about storing billboard locations in a quad tree for quick access.

[image]

Comment: @Rabbid76 if you approve of my summary of your answer, please say so and I'll flag my post as answered. Thank you

Comment: A lot of good trial and error backed up with results and tradeoffs. Answering your own question as you explore the issue provides the site with really good content.